# get content from page through AJAX wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, jquery

I'm using an wordpress theme and I want to load content from a page inside a div from another page.

Here is the code from the page which I want to load inside the div :

**page-usercomments.php** (this is a custom page template where I retrieve comments of the current user)

```
<?php

    get_header();

?>

    <div id="primary" class="row">

        <div id="content" class="span9" role="main">

    <!-- GET CURRENT USER -->

    <?php

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
    ?>


   <!-- GET COMMENTS OF USER -->
    <?php 
    $args = array(
    'user_id' => $current_user->ID, // use user_id
    'post_type' => 'debate'
     );
    $comments = get_comments($args);

    ?>
     <ol class="commentlist">
            <?php
              wp_list_comments(
  array(
    'per_page' => 10, //Allow comment pagination
    'reverse_top_level' => false //Show the latest comments at the top of the list
  ), 
  $comments
);
            ?>
        </ol><!-- .commentlist -->
        </div><!-- #content .site-content -->

    </div><!-- #primary .content-area -->

<?php get_footer(); // This fxn gets the footer.php file and renders it ?>
```

I want to get the output of this page inside a div from another page and I'm thinking to use **AJAX** and this is the code:

**UPDATE:**

```
     $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url:"http://www.mywebsite.co/cpt/user-comments",
     cache: false,
     dataType: 'html',
     success: function(data){
               $("#div").append(data);        //   <--- look here
    },
     error: function(){ },
     complete: function(){ }
    });

    });
```

**LATER UPDATE:  I'VE RESOLVED THIS BY USING THE WORDPRESS **[AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)****

Is this the correct way to do it ?

And also,  I don't know how should I add the url because the permalink created for the page which I want to retrieve is **"mywebsite.com/user-comments"**
Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my ajax function...

*You send your ajaxcall, and when it return with success code, get the data, and put it into your div.*

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: yourUrl,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
               $("#div").append(data);        //   <--- look here
    },
    error: function(){ },
    complete: function(){ }
});
```

Comment: I've added this url : **"http://www.mywebsite.com/user-comments"** and I'm getting :                                                      `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`             What's wrong?

Comment: you have error in success ? instead of 'div.append.data' can you ' alert(data)'... the data received is maybe not html, or, maybe your url is not correct ? here is the doc : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I've added `"` inside the URL because that was missing and added alert instead of append and now I'm getting: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mywebsite.co/user-comments?_=1386084921073. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mywebsite.co' is therefore not allowed access. `

Comment: I will accept your answer because this is the correct way to do it, however the best way to solve my issue is by using the wordpress ajax api.